# Create file inside .app on OS X application

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering if it is possible to make a new file inside the existing application? Now i am using:

```
[filemgr createFileAtPath: @"newFile.txt" contents: data attributes: nil];
```

But I think I have to change the path to something else. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good idea.  If the app is installed at `/Application/` then only admin users launch the app will be able to write that file.  (Never assume users are admins!)

The application might also be on read-only media.

If might also interfere with digitally signed applications though I'm not sure.  Changing a file within the bundle means the app has changed, which is essentially what digital signatures want to avoid.  (Don't mess with application bundles)

Instead, you should save a file on `~/Library/Application Support/<yourApplicationName>/`.

Read [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672).

Comment: +1 Also, applications can live on read-only media like DVDs, disk images, network shares, etc.